# NPE when debugging android app in physical device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I've set up my device drivers, eclipse is finding it without problem, I can execute the app in my phone, also debug the view in Chrome, but when I try to `Debug as > Android application` I can see app starting in the device, it tries to attach the debugger and then I always get this error:

```
2015-02-23 10:58:31 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.launchInBackground(DebugUIPlugin.java:1292)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.launch(DebugUITools.java:766)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.debugRunningApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:178)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(AndroidLaunchController.java:1749)
at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:926)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:775)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:936)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.handleHELO(HandleHello.java:175)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.handleChunk(HandleHello.java:81)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:336)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: @StephenC im with Eclipse Luna, your link charmly helped, I've edited your answer with workaround resume and accepted. Thanks!

Comment: I rejected your edit because (IMO) it didn't make sense as an edit to my answer.  It would be appropriate as a either a comment ... or as a "self-answer".

Comment: to have the solution in the answer and no to a related link is in the SO suggestions, I can't understand YO, but ok... done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround related in Eclipse / Android issue [20990](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20990) works for me.

> this does not seem to occur upon first launch.  i have my launch config set to "Always Ask" for the device; this seems to occur either as a result of or as a reason for that dialog not appearing on some of my attempts to re-launch.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an example of Eclipse / Android issue [20990](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20990).  The issue tracker doesn't indicate that a fix is available, though one of the followups suggests some possible workarounds.